# Liferay project: Use Facet Search to implement search by category with "logic and"

Tags: liferay, faceted-search

I want to search out webcontent objects by categoryids. I have defined two groups of category

- Marketing:

  - AA, BB, CC, DD
- Country:

  - America, France, German

I want to find a WebContent which contains [AA, France]. The logic should be 'AA *and* France'. So I defined a JSON file which is used to load the search condition. But I found my JSON file execute the search with 'AA *or* France':

```
{
  className: 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.facet.MultiValueFacet',
  data: {
    displayStyle: 'list',
    frequencyThreshold: 1,
    showAssetCount: true,
    values:[AA, France]
  },
  displayStyle: 'asset_categories',
  fieldName: 'assetCategoryIds',
  label: 'category',
  order: 'OrderHitsDesc',
  static: true,
  weight: 1.3
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to implement the logic with '*and*'?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should be `'values': ['AA', 'France']` - allthough some parsers read that invalid JSON (see http://json.org/ for more on this).

If you look at the implementation of `MultiValueFacet.doGetFacetClause()` you will see:

```
 ...
    facetQuery.add(termQuery, BooleanClauseOccur.SHOULD);
 ...
```

The `BooleanClauseOccur.SHOULD` expresses the *OR* logic. If you need an *AND* logic, you have to implement your own `Facet` (in an *Ext Plugin*). You can take `MultiValueFacet` as blueprint and replace `BooleanClauseOccur.SHOULD` with `BooleanClauseOccur.MUST`.

If you think this is something for a feature request - you can create one in the [Liferay issues database](http://issues.liferay.com/).